# Add custom fields for Order Line Items in Magento via module

Tags: product, admin, orders

I want to add custom order line items in Magento via module

I just found one link:

http://www.webcenter.co.in/how-to-add-custom-fields-for-order-line-items-in-magento

But here we have to do changes in code how can I do it via module.

Basically I want to add custom text field to product detail page and save its value to be available in checkout and order detail in admin.

Comment: Please review the answer provided and accept it if it solved your question. Alternately provide further feedback.

Answer (score 1):

[A quick Google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Magento%20%2B%20custom%20order%20field) pointed me to the following options:

- [Custom field in checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-field-in-checkout.html) - Free
- [Additional Checkout Attributes – Custom Fields Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/additional-checkout-attributes-custom-fields-manager.html) - $ 89

And so on.